How to streamline code with multiple non-contiguous ranges
I have a worksheet that project managers (PM) use to configure large systems. The worksheet has four sections that represent each of four panels. Within each panel, the PM must select one of the four options for Fluid Type and one of the two options for Control Type. For this example, E, G, I and K are the columns to select.
Panel 1
Fluid Type Options E, G, I, K (row 9)
Control Type Options E, G (row 10)
Panel 2
Fluid Type Options E, G, I, K (row 21)
Control Type Options E, G (row 22)
Panel 3 & 4 are the same, but different rows of course.
The following code works great. If I click on E9 the cell turns blue AND G9, I9 and K9 have no fill color. If I then click on I9, then it turns blue and E9, G9 and K9 have no fill color, etc.
Is there a way to streamline this code?
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim r1a As Range
    Dim r1b As Range
    Dim r2a As Range
    Dim r2b As Range
    Dim r3a As Range
    Dim r3b As Range
    Dim r4a As Range
    Dim r4b As Range
        Set r1a = Range("E9, G9, I9, K9")
        Set r1b = Range("E10,G10")
        Set r2a = Range("E21, G21, I21, K21")
        Set r2b = Range("E22,G22")
        Set r3a = Range("E32, G32, I32, K32")
        Set r3b = Range("E33,G33")
        Set r4a = Range("E43, G43, I43, K43")
        Set r4b = Range("E44,G44")
        r1a.Name = "P1FT"
        r1b.Name = "P1CT"
        r2a.Name = "P2FT"
        r2b.Name = "P2CT"
        r3a.Name = "P3FT"
        r3b.Name = "P3CT"
        r4a.Name = "P4FT"
        r4b.Name = "P4CT"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P1FT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P1FT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("P1CT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P1CT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("P2FT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P2FT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("P2CT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P2CT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("P3FT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P3FT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("P3CT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P3CT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("P4FT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P4FT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("P4CT")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("P4CT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
    End If
End Sub


No need to give a range a name to access it. You can directly write
Set r1a = Range("E9, G9, I9, K9")
If Not Intersect(Target, r1a) Is Nothing Then
    r1a.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
End If

But as you are doing the same stuff on all of your 8 ranges, I would create a small routine that handles one range and call that routine 8 times.
Your code can then simply look like this:
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E9, G9, I9, K9")
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E10, G10")
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E21, G21, I21, K21")
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E22, G22")
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E32, G32, I32, K32")
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E33, G33")
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E43, G43, I43, K43")
    MarkSelectedCellInRange target, Range("E44, G44")
End Sub

Sub MarkSelectedCellInRange(selectedCell As Range, panel As Range)
    If Intersect(selectedCell, panel) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    ' No hit
    panel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    selectedCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
End Sub


Hi FunThomas!  I copy/pasted the second block of code, per your comments. This code is so nicely streamlined, but it's not working.

I just tried the code in the first block and that doesn't work for me either.

Hold the phone! They work. I was in Design Mode. Do I need the Cancel As Boolean?Thank you FunThomas so very much! For my next feat, I have to do the same for rows of checkboxes. Thanks again!!!!

Hi, yes you need the cancel parameter. All event routines (=routines that are triggered by Excel automatically when some happens, eh a Doubleclick event) are prefefined and needs to be exactly as Excel expects them, else they will not be called.

@VBasic2008 I also tested your code and it works great too. It is nice to have a couple of options. Thank you!!!

A Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick: Highlight Single Cell of Range
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim RangeAddresses() As Variant: RangeAddresses = VBA.Array( _
        "E9,G9,I9,K9", "E10,G10", "E21,G21,I21,K21", "E22,G22", _
        "E32,G32,I32,K32", "E33,G33", "E43,G43,I43,K43", "E44,G44")
    Dim ColorNumber As Long: ColorNumber = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'blue
        
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(RangeAddresses)
        With Me.Range(RangeAddresses(n))
            If Not Intersect(Target, .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Target.Interior.Color = ColorNumber
                Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next n
                
End Sub

